# ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing tool parameters - default settings

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, parameters, mobile-map-package

I would like to set my ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing tool parameters to a default value for repeated routine update cycles. The primary tools I'm using are "Create Vector Tile Package" and "Create Mobile Map Package". For example, in the "Create Vector Tile Package" settings, I'd like to have the "Package for ArcGIS Online, Bing Maps, Google Maps" option automatically set to be unchecked.

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you are comfortable with. I think this could be done using ModelBuilder or Python (either script tool, or Python toolbox).

Either way, what you would do is essentially make a "tool" that has these parameters pre-populated, and mimics the other parameters necessary for the tool you'd like to run. Your tool would then simply call the original geoprocessing tool and pass all parameters.